# Unable to get terrain loaded with PhysicsEditor-Extension to collide

Tags: java, android, andengine

For my android game, based around AndEngine, I am currently working on loading levels.

I came across [AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension](https://github.com/ANDLABS-Git/AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension), which loads an XML and graphics exported by [PhysicsEditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor).

I am now working on creating a class, conveniently named MapLoader, which takes a map name and calls the PhysicsEditor Extension to load the appropriate files and register them. The problem is that while the graphics are displayed as intended, anything else in the scene pass right through it without colliding.

Here's how the MapLoader is invoked:

```
MapLoader loader = new MapLoader(this, engine, world); // (Context, PhysicsWorld, Scene)
loader.loadMap("testmap1");
```

And here's the important bits of the MapLoader class:

```
// Constructor
public void loadMap(String mapName) {

    this.atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(game.getTextureManager(), 2048, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    atlas.load();
    PhysicsEditorLoader loader = new PhysicsEditorLoader();
    this.tMap = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.atlas, game, "maps/" + mapName + ".png", 0, 0);
    this.sMap = new Sprite(0, 500, this.tMap, game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.world.attachChild(sMap);
    try {
        loader.load(game, engine, "maps/" + mapName + ".xml", sMap, true, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("XML load failure");
    }

    this.sMap = new Sprite(0, 0, this.tMap, game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    world.attachChild(sMap);

    world.registerUpdateHandler(engine);

}

// .......Snip...........


// loadMap method
public void loadMap(String mapName) {

    this.atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(game.getTextureManager(), 2048, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    atlas.load();
    final PhysicsEditorLoader loader = new PhysicsEditorLoader();
    this.tMap = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.atlas, game, "maps/" + mapName + ".png", 0, 0);
    this.sMap = new Sprite(0, 500, this.tMap, game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.world.attachChild(sMap);
    try {
        loader.load(game, engine, "maps/" + mapName + ".xml", sMap, true, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.sMap = new Sprite(0, 0, this.tMap, game.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    world.attachChild(sMap);

    world.registerUpdateHandler(engine);

}
```

Did i miss something? I based the above code on the [example](https://github.com/ANDLABS-Git/AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension-Examples).

I've tried editing the source to point to a non-existing directory for the XML loading, after which it started complaining, indicating that the XML is found.

---

**Edit:** In case something inherently wrong with the XML is suspected, I've uploaded it for inspection [here](http://jarmund.net/testmap1.xml). It was created in PhysicsEditor by adding sprite, using the shape tracer to get the outline, and export as AndEngine exporter. The XML is stored in `assets/maps/` with the associated sprite stored in `assets/gfx/maps/`

**PS:** Until i get this test working I'm using the trial version of PhysicsEditor. I do not believe it affects the outcome.